# How to create .po file for vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, translation, gettext, po

I’ve been researching on how to translate my vue project but I’m getting kinda stuck.
I’ve been asked to create a .po file (that I can then use in [poedit](https://poedit.net/) or something similar).

I’ve tried implementing [vue-gettext](https://github.com/Polyconseil/vue-gettext) but I’m a bit confused on how to work it. I’ve added [easygettext](https://github.com/Polyconseil/easygettext) as needed but I keep getting module errors:

```
./node_modules/easygettext/src/extract-cli.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
```

I tried to fix it by adding [BannerPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/)(as per this suggestion: [How to keep my shebang in place using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755149/how-to-keep-my-shebang-in-place-using-webpack)) in both `webpack.dev.conf.js` and `webpack.prod.conf.js`:

```
require('webpack').BannerPlugin

plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({ banner: "#!/usr/bin/env node", raw: true }),
...
```

but I'm still having the error.

additionally, it seems I need a translations.json file to use the  `vue-gettext`  plugin but it also looks like the translations.json is created after by [gettext-compile](https://github.com/Polyconseil/easygettext#gettext-compile) so I'm unsure if I'm supposed to first create a json file of translations or what is needed.

So I’m wondering if anybody knows  **how to setup vue-gettext properly or if there are any alternatives to create .po files?**

Thanks so much!

Comment: There are several different ways to support languages in VueJS, but I understand that vue-gettext should work fine.  And, of course, vue-gettext should fully support .po format files.  SUGGESTION: Look here: https://vuejsexamples.com/translate-your-vue-js-applications-with-gettext/  Notice the step translating your .po into .json.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks so much! If I understand correctly, I can generate a .po by annotating the strings and then using easygettext to extract into .po file?

Comment: diff framework, but for an old and large angularjs proj we use the angular-gettext library, which has a corresponding grunt build tool (grunt-angular-gettext) that extracts translatable strings in your code into a .pot file. 

Then you use poedit to create/edit a po file for each language you wish. That gives you the en_US.po file, for instance. The grunt build tool takes that po file and creates an en_US.json file in your target folder, which is loaded into the browser.

Last i checked, nothing for vue quite matches the capability of angular-gettext.